# Using CWinFormControl from an ActiveX Control

Tags: .net, c++, mfc, activex

I'm trying to host a managed control (C#/.Net) inside an ActiveX Control (MFC/C++/CLR Enabled.)

I've been able to use CWinFormsControl successfully from an MFC View based application, but I haven't figured out how to host one in an ActiveX Control. The ActiveX control is CLR enabled. We're attempting to do this because we have a legacy MFC application that needs to make use of a third party managed control, and we must host it inside of our own ActiveX control, which is then hosted in our application. Long story, but this is how it must work.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into interop between COM and .NET. As far as I remember, you can start by making your .NET component COM visible for your ActiveX control. After that, your .NET component acts as another COM component.

Here is an article about the interop. I believe you need to [read Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx).

Comment: This answer is good. Definitely let the .NET COM interop layer do the work for you here. Your scenario sounds overly complicated, though. Perhaps there's a way to shed some of the layers in between things here...? (Or maybe not.) Hopefully, treating the .NET entity as an ActiveX control makes it easier for you to embed inside your existing ActiveX control. Controls that contain other controls have always been challenging. Mixing models like this can really twist you up in thinking knots at times...

Comment: As it turns out, I didn't notice my CREATESTRUCT params for X and Y were at -32000, which resulted in the control being drawn off in space. It was there all along, I just couldn't see it. Sorry for all the fuss.